# How to use gotev:uploadservice having compileSdkVersion 28?

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
...
}
```

And I have these dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 '
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.4.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
}
```

I get the following error:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 27.0.2.

Apparently the problem is with the gotev upload service library since checking its build.gradle I found that it has the following lines of code:

```
def supportLibraryVersion = "27.0.2"

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibraryVersion}"
}
```

Comment: Namely Gainder's answer.

Comment: if i had to use it with compiled sdk 28 i would have downloaded the project , then add in my project in some package , it a long way though

Comment: @TheWanderer, thanks, Gainder's answer does not work for me but Adarsh's answer solved my problem.